# Place a script within a script

Tags: javascript, string, slice

I need to insert the results of a script inside another script which is being sent to Google Reviews. I have this so far, which extracts and displays the last 2 characters of a country code:

```js
onDOMContentLoaded = (function(){
    var str = "United Kingdom UK";
    var res = str.slice(-2);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
})();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

This shows the code inside a p tag, but I need it to display in the code below:

```js
window.renderOptIn = function() {
    window.gapi.load('surveyoptin', function() {
      window.gapi.surveyoptin.render(
        {
          "delivery_country": "RESULT GOES HERE",
          });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like all you need to do is run that `window` function instead of the DOM manipulation you had already.  So the first block would become:

```
onDOMContentLoaded = (function(){
    var str = "United Kingdom UK";
    var res = str.slice(-2);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
    window.renderOptIn(res);
})();
```

and the window function should be changed a bit to this:

```
window.renderOptIn = function(res) {
    window.gapi.load('surveyoptin', function() {
      window.gapi.surveyoptin.render(
        {
          "delivery_country": res,
          });
     });
  }
```

Let me know if you have any other questions.  And definitely throw some `console.log`s in there to make sure everything is firing at the right time with the right info.